# Fiddler doesn't work

Tags: fiddler, makecert, certenroll

Fiddler almost not work for me. Seems the problem only with https.
For example to open https google.com I need to wait around 40 seconds

Screenshots:

[immediately after request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6GmY.png)

[after ~40 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGHT3.png)

Fiddler log:

```
18:02:46:3326 Fiddler Running...
18:02:46:3922 Windows 8+ AppContainer isolation feature detected.
18:03:09:5427 Assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\CertMaker.dll' was not found. Using default Certificate Generator.
18:03:09:5467 /Fiddler.CertMaker> Using Fiddler.DefaultCertificateProvider+CertEnrollEngine for certificate generation; UseWildcards=False.
18:03:11:3745 HTTPSLint> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255 bytes. githubcom /ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance
18:03:11:3855 HTTPSLint> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255 bytes. githubcom /ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance
18:03:11:3895 HTTPSLint> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255 bytes. githubcom /ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance
18:03:11:3915 HTTPSLint> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255 bytes. githubcom /ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance
18:03:11:3945 HTTPSLint> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255 bytes. githubcom /ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance
18:03:20:2192 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6091.
18:03:20:3110 [Fiddler] No HTTP request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6134.
18:03:20:3120 [Fiddler] No HTTP request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6130.
18:03:28:8160 HTTPSLint> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255 bytes. githubcom /ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance
18:03:30:2198 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6095.
18:03:30:2198 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6097.
18:03:30:2198 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6099.
18:03:30:2198 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6101.
18:03:50:2219 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6163.
18:03:50:2219 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6141.
18:03:50:2219 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6167.
18:04:10:2230 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6176.
18:04:10:2230 [Fiddler] No HTTPS request was received from (chrome:10428) new client socket, port 6179.
```

Many times in chrome I see: Waiting for proxy tunnel...and site shows  This webpage is not available (ERR_TIMED_OUT)

In EDGE I even can't open http site for all sub requests I see blue up arrow which means fiddler trying to load it (after ~40 seconds I get loaded all that requests)

I tried to reset Internet Properties-> Advanced tab-> Restore advanced settings - it doesn't help me.
Also I tried to  restarted my system, also I restarted fiddler after any changes I made.

Fiddler settings:
Certificates generated by CertEnroll engine. I tried to change it to MakeCert. Few times I reset All certificates, also manually removes certificates.
Browsers: Chrome/Firefox

Gateway info in fiddler: No upstream gateway proxy is configured.

Recently I made clear installation of Windows 10.
I do not have any Antivirus.

Windows 10 Pro x64
Fiddler v4.6.2.0

I need fiddler for my work. Please help me

UPDATED:

This is can be issue with Protocols. Currently in fiddler I have next protocols:

```
fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to www.bing.com (for #4) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

and

```
fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to www.google.com.ua (for #23) failed. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler

Comment: Thank you! But I installed fiddler many times on diff machines and usually it works fine for me, but not now.

Comment: You need to run on compatible mode for Windows 8

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to do this. It didn't help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: I think that certificate installation problem. Here is link for Certificate installation http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddlerForWin8

Comment: This is can be issue with Protocols. Currently in fiddler I have next protocols: <client>;ssl2;ssl3 and in internet explorer I had ticked only: tsl 1.0,tsl1.1,tsl1.2. I tried to play with this settings: fiddler behavior little bit changed, some sites starts to work with https but I see a lot of errors like: fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to www.bing.com (for #4) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought the issue was with protocols enabled in Internet Options in Windows and Fiddler protocols.

I ticked Use SSL 3.0 and use TSL 1.0 in Interent properties (all other should be unticked)
in Fiddler protocols I typed: ;ssl3;tls1.0

And after this changes everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use SSL 3.0 and use TSL 1.0 in Internet properties for it to work. Previously I also did the same mistake but now working fine. I also checked on [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for the same.